# How to test that a WPF Storyboard was started?

Tags: c#, wpf, testing, xunit.net

I have created a simple custom WPF control that allows injecting a `Storyboard` via a dependency property. In response to changes to the control's `Content`, the control calls `Begin()` on that storyboard. This actually works fine in practice. [See code at the end of this post]

I am now trying to write an xUnit test to verify that this happens. When debugging the test I can see that the `Begin()` method is indeed called. However, I struggle to verify this with my test. I would love to simply use a `Mock<Storyboard>` but unfortunately, the `Begin()`-method cannot be mocked as it is not overrideable.

Being unable to come up with a solution for registering the call to `Begin()` and inspired by the unit tests in MahApps.Metro (e.g. [FlyoutTest.cs](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/Mahapps.Metro.Tests/Tests/FlyoutTest.cs)), I tried using a `TaskCompletionSource` and assigned a handler to `Storyboard.Completed`. The idea was that checking for completion was the next best thing to checking for the storyboard starting. After all, if it completes that means it must have been started...

However, even though I can see in the debugger that my code does indeed call the storyboard's `Begin()` method as intended, for some yet unknown reason the Storyboard's `Completed` event never fires and thus the completion source is awaited forever. **This is what I'm trying solve at the moment.** I suspect the solution will involve dispatchers but I have only very little experience with those.
I already tried putting the `sut.Content = ...` line in a `root.Dispatcher.Invoke()` but that apparently wasn't enough...

Here's my current test code with some comments added:

```
[StaFact]
public async Task TestContentChangedTriggersStoryboard()
{
    // set up the dummy storyboard:
    var storyboard = new Storyboard { Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMillisconds(100)) };
    var dummyAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0d, 1d, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dummyAnimation, new PropertyPath(FrameworkElement.TagProperty));
    storyboard.Children.Add(dummyAnimation);

    // set up a way to track whether storyboard actually runs
    var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    storyboard.Completed += (s, e) => completionSource.SetResult(true);
    storyboard.Freeze();

    // set up the subject under test and assign the dummy storyboard:
    var sut = new BaseAnimatedContentControl { Content = "Blah", Storyboard = storyboard }

    // set up the visual container for the control to get the control's template properly initialized:
    var root = new Popup();
    root.BeginInit();
    root.Child = sut;
    root.EndInit();
    root.IsOpen = true;

    // ensure intial state:
    Assert.Null(sut.OldContent);
    Assert.Equal("Blah", sut.Content);
    Assert.Null(sut.Tag);

    sut.Content = "Blubb"; // <- this triggers the code which starts the `Storyboard`
    
    // verify that the storyboard got called and await the storyboard's completion: (the test currently never moves beyond this)
    bool completed = await completionSource.Task;
    Assert.True(completed);

    // verify the effects of the tested code:
    Assert.Equal("Blah", sut.OldContent);
    Assert.Equal("Blubb", sut.Content);
    Assert.Equal(1, sut.Tag);
}
```

Note:

- I'm using a `Popup` here rather than a `Window` because it is less intrusive during tests (i.e. it does not show up at all), but I also already tried with `Window` and it did not make a difference. It is essentially just a shortcut for ensuring the ControlTemplate's visual tree has been properly initialized so I can access the defined template parts. If there is another, better way to do this without having to instantiate a visual container, please feel free to comment.

Any ideas how else to do this?

---

**Update:** I have now completely overhauled the question text, especially the source code. I have also moved parts that were mentioned in the original question (and in the comments below) to a new descendant class, so this one only contains the functionality I'm interested in at the moment and nothing else (though that was not the reason for doing it). Hopefully, this is now more understandable.

---

For completeness, here is the current implementation of the class I'm trying to test:

```
    public class BaseAnimatedContentControl : ContentControl
    {
        static BaseAnimatedContentControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BaseAnimatedContentControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BaseAnimatedContentControl)));
        }

        public object? OldContent
        {
            get => GetValue(OldContentProperty);
            protected set => SetValue(OldContentPropertyKey, value);
        }
        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey OldContentPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(OldContent), typeof(object), typeof(BaseAnimatedContentControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty OldContentProperty = OldContentPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

        public Storyboard? Storyboard { get => (Storyboard?)GetValue(StoryboardProperty); set => SetValue(StoryboardProperty, value); }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StoryboardProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Storyboard), typeof(Storyboard), typeof(BaseAnimatedContentControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
        {
            if (Storyboard != null && (oldContent != null || OldContent != null) && oldContent != newContent)
            {
                OldContent = oldContent;
                Storyboard.Begin(this, Template);
            }
            base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should understand that you must not test framework code or 3rd party library code. You only test the framework client and library client code (your code). In your case you don't have to test whether the Storyboard runs/behaves properly. Microsoft already did that for you before they release the class. Writing unit tests for controls or UI in general is not that straight forward as you might think. You will encounter a lot of problems from the fact that there is no rendering test surface to the fact that your unit tests usually execute during build.

Comment: I guess you don't want the tests to popup all kinds of controls and UI. Test should execute quick. Apart from rendering a UI test would also need an element tree in order to allow resources and data bindings to resolve. To test UI and UI interaction behavior you usually implement automated UI tests. WPF provides a framework for this (for example [Test Run - Automating UI Tests In WPF Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/march/test-run-automating-ui-tests-in-wpf-applications).

Comment: @BionicCode : To clarify: `AnimatedContentControl` is my own class and that is the one that is supposed to start the storyboard so I think it is perfectly valid to write a test for that. I am in the process of writing a custom control library. I might have confused you with mentioning MahApps.Metro? I was only using that as inspiration because they also created unit tests for their controls...

Comment: Your title alone (*How to test that a WPF Storyboard has run?*) implies that you are testing a Storyboard to assert that it has completed. Your posted test case only asserts that the Storyboard has completed. And that is what Microsoft already has tested. In addition to handling the Completed event you can also assert that the animated property has changed to the expected target value (if you believe that this particular test case makes sense). However, I was just hinting that you use automated UI tests in order to test UI and that unit tests for UI elements are problematic.

Comment: You are right in that storyboard completion is not *really* what I was interested in... it merely seemed to be the next most achievable thing to what I was really after, seeing that the `Storyboard` class cannot be mocked in a useful manner... I'm testing for completion because completion implies that the Storyboard was started in the first place...
Ideally, I'd be able to simply test whether my class's code calls the injected storyboard's `Begin()` method in response to its `Content` property changing. That in itself does not really have anything to do with the UI AFAICT...

Comment: ...and as you mentioned it: Testing whether an animated property is actually changed by the Storyboard would be fine for my purposes, too. If only I could figure out how to let the test wait for that to happen without freezing the test runner. That is really the whole problem I'm trying to solve at the moment...
To clarify:  I don't really care which property gets changed - that is ultimately up to the provider of the storyboard.

Comment: If you have a complex logic that is part of an operation and this logic is part of a 3rd party library you would have to treat it as a black box by hiding it (encapsulation) behind an interface (or abstraction). For example, create a class e.g. Animator that controls the animation. Let Animator implement an IAnimator interface. Use constructor (or property) injection. In your unit test inject a mock of IAnimator.

Comment: Again, you must not test 3rd party or framework code. Proper encapsulation or applying the Single Responsibility principle helps you to write testable code. When writing code identify such "black box" code. Whether you follow encapsulation or the SRP strictly or not: "black box" code must always be encapsulated i.e. hidden behind an interface. Apart from extensibility it's a fundamental part of writing testable code. Test Driven Development is another practice that helps to identify such code and also eliminates code refactoring in order to convert untestable code like yours into testable code

Comment: I still believe that you should feel quite uncomfortable in your guts about unit tests that cause to popup windows and run animations. I guess you will have to experience it yourself in order to understand this. Let me know if you need help to refactor your control in order to enable convenient unit testing.

Comment: Because your Storyboard does not contain any animations the Completed event is never raised (there is no animation to start). It must contain at least one animation e.g. DoubleAnimation.

Comment: See this example from the docs to learn how to create a Storyboard animation with C#: [How to: Animate a Property by Using a Storyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-a-property-by-using-a-storyboard?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#example)

Comment: Please actually read what I have written before, both in my question and here in the comments: A: There is NO 3rd party code! B: My actual code does indeed involve another player (only referenced via an interface named `IContentTransition`) and I am indeed already mocking it. I left it out of my example to keep things simple for illustration and because the presence of that component has no impact on my actual issue (believe me, I tried). [...]

Comment: ... C: It also does not make any difference whether the storyboard contains any animations - with or without animations, the test runner always freezes at the `await`-line. Again, I left that out of my example for brevity only.

Comment: And thanks for the link but I am quite comfortable with using Storyboards for animations... but this isn't about creating storyboards at all. That is completely offloaded to the consumers of my class who merely provide their storyboard to it. That's why I don't care about the actual contents of the storyboard but only whether it gets started at the right moment...

Comment: What I'm essentially trying to do is write tests similar in principle to the ones found here: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/develop/src/Mahapps.Metro.Tests/Tests (and yes, I know they are not using storyboards here, but they are also initiating actions the results of which need to be verified asynchronously which is also what I'm trying to do here...)

Comment: *"Please actually read what I have written before"* - I did for sure. *"A: There is NO 3rd party code!"* - I know. I was just general. I also said framework code. Your unit test should not involve any Storyboard as this is a framework functionality that you usually want to mock. That's why I was suggesting to encapsulate this logic.

Comment: *"I left it out of my example to keep things simple for illustration"* - I can only make suggestions based on what you show. *"B: My actual code does indeed involve another player (only referenced via an interface named IContentTransition) and I am indeed already mocking it. "* - You probably got me wrong. You wrote that you were not able to *"use a Mock<Storyboard> but unfortunately, the Begin()-method cannot be mocked as it is not overrideable."*. Not sure what you're about now. I was suggesting a solution that completely avoids any Storyboard or a mocked Storyboard.

Comment: *"Again, I left that out of my example for brevity only."* - It's really not helpful to post code that is not behaving like the original code when you ask for a review to find an issue with your code. Check if the Completed event is raised.

Comment: *"Check if the Completed event is Raised"* - yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do and it is not working (i.e. it is freezing the test runner). That is exactly what this is all about. I have now tried to clarify things a little more in my original question based on your comments and also added back an animation. Does that make it clearer what I'm trying to do and why and what the actual problem is that I'm trying to solve?

Comment: I absolutely understand that you're trying to help and I truly appreciate that but you seem to be very focused on things that are not at all what is (currently) bugging me... ;) This is (currently) not about improving my control's code (I am fully aware that there is potential for further optimization) but only about getting the test to at least run and verify the current behaviour - and not just freeze/wait indefinitely.

Comment: *"It's really not helpful to post code that is not behaving like the original code"* Just wanted to clarify that the posted code does indeed behave exactly like the original code (in that it has exactly the same outcome). As I wrote, I tried it both with and without the omitted parts. I tried to condense the example to the minimal amount of code that still exhibited the same behaviour as the more verbose original, thus culling out everything that was obviously not contributing to the problem and could thus be unnecessarily distracting... apparently the absence was even more distracting... ;)

Comment: If you're going to test UI behaviour then you will hit weird issues without full on UI running. People do test that sort of thing but using UI automation. I believe the current approach recommended by ms is appium and winappdriver. These are full integration tests show windows and suchlike.

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit `Storyboard` and add a mockable interface, as shown below.

```cs
public interface IStoryboard
{
    void Begin();
    // etc
}

public class MyStoryboard : Storyboard, IStoryboard
{
    public new MyStoryboard Clone() 
    {
        return (MyStoryboard)base.Clone();
    }
}
```

If you use the `IStoryboard` interface in your custom control, you should be able to mock your storyboard. E.g.:

```cs
var storyboardMock = new Mock<IStoryboard>();
```

Comment: Well, the downside I would see to this approach is that this way I would have to essentially force the users of my control to use `MyStoryboard` instead of plain old `Storyboard` in their XAML... also, I would then be "burdened" with keeping the signature of `IStoryboard` in sync with Microsoft's `Storyboard`... So, yes, it would probably solve the issue of mockability but I'm not yet convinced about the cost to benefit ratio...

Comment: Then I would suggest to go for [shims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-shims-to-isolate-your-application-from-other-assemblies-for-unit-testing?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp). Horrendous concept if you ask me, but it will probably solve your problem. Simply fake `PresentationFramework.dll`...